# What happens to PendingIntents when user updates the app?

Tags: android, google-play, android-pendingintent

I know that the data, like in sharedprefs files, doesnt get erased when a user updates his app, but what about a scheduled Broadcast? Does the PendingIntent get canceled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PendingIntent`s do not get canceled or deleted when the app is updated. If you've scheduled alarms before the update, those alarms will trigger after the update at the expected times.

However, if you uninstall the app, all `PendingIntent`s, alarms, private data, databases, etc. are canceled/deleted.